# How to make a number argument a variable?

Tags: ruby

How do I make a number argument a variable?

For example:

Snippet 1:

```
a=1
a_7 = a+6
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ"
letter_7 = alphabet.slice[a_7..a_7]
```

Snippet 2:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ"
letter_7 = alphabet.slice[7..7]
```

I would like to make snippet 1 have the same outcome as snippet 2, with a variable as the arguments within `slice` action. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Both these snippets give an error. What is your desired output for each snippet?

Comment: you need to use `()` instead of `[]` for the `slice` method. If you change that, both snippets return `H` as the result.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Sorry, the first snippet is supposed to give an error - it's just wrong. The second is supposed to save the eighth letter of the alphabet to letter_7, so letter_7 = "H".

Comment: @davidhu2000 Thank you!

Comment: Your tag "rubygems" is not relevant to your question (even if someone suggests you use a particular gem, which I think is doubtful), so you should remove it. Many members use tags to filter questions that they want to see (or don't want to see), so it's important that they be appropriate. Just "ruby" is fine.

Comment: In future I suggest you hold off choosing an answer so quickly. A quick selection may discourage other answers and may short-circuit others who are still preparing answers. The point is that there's no rush, just don't forget. I suggest waiting at least a couple of hours. Many here wait much longer. When you have time read over the [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I recommend waiting 24 hours, which gives the user's around the world a chance to chime in. Also, there are a number of excellent users who only get on every couple days. As @CarySwoveland says, picking quickly doesn't help you and it discourages better answers that might take a while. I'd also recommend reading "[ask]" and the linked pages, especially http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Fair enough. Apologies, I'll be sure to hold off on my next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue come from the fact that you are using the `slice` method without any arguments. You can not use `[]` with the `slice` method. To make this work, you need to change `[]` to `()`

```
letter_7 = alphabet.slice(7..7)
```

This will actually return `H` as the result, because arrays index start at 0, so to get the 7th letter, you will need to slice at index 6.

```
letter_7 = alphabet.slice(6..6) #=> 'G'
```

Or, you can just use the `[]` method on the string itself.

```
letter_7 = alphabet[6] #=> 'G'
```

Of course, you can replace the index values with variables, as long as the variables are set to integers.

```
a = 6

letter_7 = alphabet[a] #=> 'G'
```